# Adding line breaks ( \r\n\r\n ) to a text/plain email

Tags: php

Just stuck with oddly stupid problem - linebreaks **\r\n** don't work with text/plain
(sent via PHP). Found temporary solution which is:

```
. PHP_EOL;
```

But I'd like to understand what is wrong with \r\n
I receive them as a plain text. Current code:

```
$note = ucwords($name).' has just sent you the file:\r\n\r\n';
```

So the received email will look like this: **User has just sent you the file:\r\n\r\n**
any hints what's wrong???

Comment: Use doubleQuotes!

$note = ucwords($name)." has just sent you the file:\r\n\r\n";

Comment: Upon my honour! Mate, haha... damn.. =)
that always teh story - weird bugs always have easy explanation. Thanks a lot. It worked... cursed double quotes! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes don't interpret special characters. You have to use doublequotes instead:

This code doesn't work:

```
$note = ucwords($name).' has just sent you the file:\r\n\r\n';
```

This code works:

```
$note = ucwords($name)." has just sent you the file:\r\n\r\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `nl2br` like

```
$note = ucwords($name).' has just sent you the file:\r\n\r\n';
$note = nl2br($note);
```